# Why console.log (Firefox), displays an object with straight brackets?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I've searched many of the existing topic, but none specific enough to pinpoint exactly where is my doubt. Just for learning. I've created a constructor function with the sole purpose of using it as the target of the function Array (to create an array obviously),then use the same function as a 'normal' constructor together with the 'new' keyword.

```
function Myray(val0,val1,val2){ 
this[0] = val0;
this[1] = val1;
this[2] = val2;
}
// Not using the 'new' keyword, but the function Array.
var res = Array.call(Myray, 'one', 'two', 'three');

console.log(res);  -->  Array(3) [ "one", "two", "three" ]
console.log(Array.isArray(res));  //  -->  true
```

Now, using the 'new' keyword normally on the same constructor, yields an    object as expected, but displayed between straight brackets as array object.

```
function Myray(val0,val1,val2){ 
this[0] = val0;
this[1] = val1;
this[2] = val2;
}
var res2 = new Myray('one','two','three');
console.log(res2);  -->  Object(3) [ "one", "two", "three" ]
```

Question is, if the function is the same. When calling the function with Array.call, Array only cares about looking at the object it is being called with, setting the inheritance chain and creating its resulting data type, in this case an array. The second call, function Object, shouldn't do the same? Why the display in straight brackets?

Comment: "*a constructor function with the sole purpose of using it as the target of the function Array*" - that doesn't work. The `Array` constructor function totally ignores the `this` value you pass in. Your call is equivalent to `var res = Array('one', 'two', 'three');`

Comment: What do you mean by "straight brackets"? The `Array` constructor is going to return an actual array and your constructor is going to return a new object when used with `new`, that's why you are getting `Array(3)` and `Object(3)`.

Comment: "*Why the display in straight brackets?*" - this has nothing to do with constructors or prototypical inheritance. The console is free to format the object as it wishes, trying to select the most useful format (and every browser does it differently). I'll guess that is uses square brackets because you have integer-indexed properties.

Comment: The question is regarding the display only. Thank you for the notes, but my belief was objects instances would display between curly brackets { }. The concepts, I get alright. Thank you.

Comment: With out new keyword you will create array variable and with new keyword you create an array object

Comment: @LuvMyDog: Historically there have always been things in javascript that developers have come to call "array-like-objects". Browser devs probably decided to display them as arrays to make web developers lives easier

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Bergi's guess, where browser's consoles are free to format as they wish, considering the constructor function has integer indexed properties.
Reason being is if running the code in a **Node.js** terminal, it displays the result between curly brackets, therefore, confirming Bergi's opinion. I should have done that before...
 Thank you all.

Comment: It's probably historical as well. Javascript is littered with array-like objects, from the object returned by jQuery to the built-in `arguments` list to nodelists returned by `getElementsByClassName`. Browser devs probably chose to honour array-like objects to make lives of web developers easier when debugging an html document.

Comment: ' It has crocodile's teeth,
  It has crocodile's mouth,
  It acts like a crocodile,
  But it is not a crocodile...'
 
Thank you slebetman.